# Operation of this circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

I have this circuit. I did the truth table but I wasn't able to understand what operations this circuit do on pair of 2-bit binary inputs (A1, A0) and (B1, B0).
I thought it was mod or div but it's not

[image: Circuit]

Comment: I don't understand your question: If you already where able to *generate* the truth table, then you must already know what the operation is – it's fully defined by that truth table; it **is** that truth table.

Comment: I think it is quite intuitive from the diagram ...

Comment: @MarcusMüller when i have 2 2-bit input 10, 10 I get 1000. I couldn't underastand the logic. 2*2 = 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is n't that a simple 2-bit multiplier ?:

[image]

No idea how can I format like this. So doing on my notebook.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am confused on q0 q1 q2 q3, do I see all the bits together? For example if I have 10x10 = 1000 (on binary). How this happens

Comment: 10x10= 0100, not 1000

Comment: because q0 is the leftmost bit

Comment: If I have a1=0 a0= 1* b1=0 b0= 1 this gives us 1000?

Comment: In the figure, it is left most. But it doesn't mean it is MSb. Figures can be drawn in any way. Qo is LSb if you imagine the numbers like I have represented in the answer 

Comment: No in that case answer is 0001. You have mixed up LSb with MSb

Comment: Thank you Meenie Leis, Now I understand. That was what confused me. The truth table that was already given to complete has q0 in the left and after q1 q2 q3 in the right and I read wrong the answer and I couldn't imagine what operation the circuit does.